# Meteor + Stylus, is there a way to dynamically re-render my styl file?

Tags: meteor, stylus

I have a bunch of mixins that I use to very quickly build UIs. This works great when I modify the `.styl` file's global variables, but is there a way to pass a `Session` variable to my stylus variables then re-render the page?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, all [stylus packages](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=stylus) are pre-processors from stylus to CSS, and run before the server sends the client bundle (HTML+CSS+JS) down the wire.

You can try using Stylus like and 3rd party library directly on the client (see http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/js.html) and [changing the stylesheet dynamically](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript).